# Augumentation methods for audio clips (RAVDESS dataset, only audio)

Tags: data-augmentation

I'm trying to augment the data of the RAVDESS dataset. I still performed many techniques over the data such as:

1. pitch tuning
2. stretching
3. shifting
4. noise adding

do you know any other way to augment the dataset? I've got almost 8000 samples at the moment.